# Hive query optimization with map join

Tags: hive, query-optimization

I have a table with 11 gb of data and the other one with 130 gb of data , and  I am doing the  update  operation , Can i use map join in hive to improve query execution optimization ? Please suggest the useful information regarding this .

Answer (score 0):

First of all please do check whether your Hive version is supporting the update functionality.

Map join will certainly help you improve the query performance 
Also apply compression techniques on the tables and then run the update command -- this will decrease the runtime.

Working on it practically will help you gain the insights.